# How to remove volume control on on player?

Tags: video.js

I would like to remove volume control on videojs player.
Anyway, when the user click on fullscreen, thevolume control must appear again.
So I want to remove volume control only when the player is not on fullscreen. Is it possible in videojs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

video.js uses styles for states such as fullscreen, so you can control this with CSS:

```
.video-js .vjs-volume-menu-button {
  display:none;
}
.video-js.vjs-fullscreen .vjs-volume-menu-button {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const videoplayer = videojs('video-player', {
            controlBar: {
                'pictureInPictureToggle': false,
                'volumePanel': false,
            }
        });
```